# Determining $\mathbf{a}^*$, $\mathbf{b}^*$, and $\mathbf{c}^*$ for reciprocal unit cell

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

We are given a unit cell with $a=4$ angstroms, $b = 6$ angstroms, and $c=8$ angstroms. $\alpha=\beta= 90^{\circ}$, $\gamma= 120^{\circ}$.

I would like to find $\mathbf{a}^*$, $\mathbf{b}^{*}$, and $\mathbf{c}^*$ for the reciprocal cell. I am not quite certain how to determine this from the information given. I know that I can find:
$$\mathbf{a}^* = 2\pi\frac{\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c})}\,,$$ however I am not sure if I am able to evaluate this with the information given. Would anyone mind helping with this problem? Many thanks :)

Comment: AFAIK, $\alpha$ is the angle between b and c. $\beta$ between a and c, $\gamma$ a and b. Is that the doubt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is to set up a cartesian coordinate system in which you embed the unit  cell and the vectors $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$. You can then determine the components of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ in the cartesian coordinate system and use the familiar formulas from vector algebra to determine the reciprocal vectors $\mathbf{a}^*$, $\mathbf{b}^*$ and $\mathbf{c}^*$ using the recipe you mentioned. Eventually, you'll be able to express the reciprocal vectors as linear combinations of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$, thus wiping out any reference to the auxiliary cartesian coordinate system.

Another way is to try and immediately express $\mathbf{a}^*$, $\mathbf{b}^*$ and $\mathbf{c}^*$ as linear combinations of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ by a series of manipulations. For example, $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$ must lie in the plane spanned by $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ (why?). Thus, we should be able to write it as a linear combination $$\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}=\alpha\mathbf{a}+\beta\mathbf{b}\,.$$ "Dotting" this with $\mathbf{b}$ we get \begin{align}
\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=0&=\alpha\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}+\beta\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b}\\
&=\alpha(4\cdot6\cdot\cos120^\circ)+\beta(6\cdot6)\\
&=-12\alpha+36\beta\,.
\end{align} "Crossing" it with $\mathbf{b}$, \begin{align}
\mathbf{b}\times(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})-\mathbf{c}(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b})=-36\mathbf{c}
\end{align} (since $\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c}=0$) or alternatively $$\mathbf{b}\times(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=\alpha\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}\,.$$ (Since $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}\,.$) Now, a drawing shows that $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}$ is antiparallel with $\mathbf{c}$. Furthermore, it has magnitude $6\cdot4\cdot\sin120^\circ=12\sqrt{3}$. Thus $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}$ is equal to $-12\sqrt{3}$ times the unit vector along $\mathbf{c}$ (which is $\mathbf{c}/\|\mathbf{c}\|=\mathbf{c}/8$) or $$\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}=-\frac{12}{8}\sqrt{3}\mathbf{c}=-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\mathbf{c}\,.$$ Hence \begin{align}
-36\mathbf{c}=\alpha\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{a}=-\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\alpha\mathbf{c}\\
\implies \left(-36+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\alpha\right)\mathbf{c}=\mathbf{0}\\
\implies \alpha=\frac{24}{\sqrt{3}}\,.
\end{align} Combining this with the result obtained by dotting $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$ with $\mathbf{b}$, we get $$0=-\frac{288}{\sqrt{3}}+36\beta\implies0=-\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}+\beta\implies\beta=\frac{8}{\sqrt{3}}\,.$$ Thus $$\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(24\mathbf{a}+8\mathbf{b}\right)\,.$$ Furthermore we have \begin{align}\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(24\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{a}+8\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(384-96\right)=\frac{288}{\sqrt{3}}\,.
\end{align} Indeed, $\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$ is the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ which is precisely $4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot\cos30^\circ=96\sqrt{3}={288}/{\sqrt{3}}\,.$ Hence we finally have $$\boxed{\mathbf{a}^*=\frac{2\pi}{288}(24\mathbf{a}+8\mathbf{b})=\frac{\pi}{18}(3\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{b})\,.}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Might I ask one brief question? If I were to try to solve this problem simply by placing the vectors into a cartesian system, how would I find the components?

Comment: Never mind, I got it figured out.

Comment: Just to make sure we’re on the same page: you can choose the $y$ and $z$ axes along $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$ respectively. So, $\mathbf{b}=6\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{c}=8\mathbf{k}$. $\mathbf{a}$ has a component $4\cos30^\circ$ along $\mathbf{i}$ and $-4\sin30^\circ$ along $\mathbf{j}$ (make a drawing to see this), so $\mathbf{a}=4(\cos30^{\circ}\mathbf{i}-\sin30^{\circ}\mathbf{j})$. You can now use the standard formulas for dot and cross products using cartesian components.

Comment: To express your results in terms of $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$ and $\mathbf{c}$, you can use $\mathbf{j}=(1/6)\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{k}=(1/8)\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{i}=(1/4\cos30^\circ)(\mathbf{a}+\sin30^{\circ}\mathbf{j})= (1/4\cos30^\circ)(\mathbf{a}+(1/6)\sin30^{\circ}\mathbf{b})$. Substituting these in your formulas for the reciprocal lattice vectors makes $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$ and $\mathbf{k}$ disappear, thus indeed removing any reference to the auxiliary cartesian coordinate system as I predicted earlier.

Comment: Just for future reference to anyone reading this:

I got

$$a* = \frac{\pi}{18} (3a +b)$$
$$b* = \frac{\pi}{54} (3a+4b)$$
$$c* = \frac{\pi}{32} c $$

Comment: Small LaTeX tip: use \vec{} or \mathbf{} for vectors and ^* for the star instead of simply *.

Comment: Thank you! I am still learning LaTeX.